# Webgrease certificate expired

Tags: .net, ssl-certificate

We use WebGrease library in our ASP.NET MVC application, I ran into a problem during our internal validation process: the latest webgrease library we downloaded from Nuget has an expired certificate!

The steps to replicate are very simple:

1. Create an ASP.NET 4.5 Web Application
2. Use Nuget to pull down the latest WebGrease library
3. Check the digital certificate of the WebGrease assembly, hitting "Advanced" button, and you will notice that the Microsoft Code Signing PCA is valid between 1/25/2013 till 4/25/2014. In other words, the digital certificate has expired long times ago.

We cannot simply bypass the internal validation process in our company, thus I am wondering if there is a process to get an updated WebGrease.dll with validate certificate? Or can I sign WebGrease open source library with my own digital certificate considering that the latest released assembly is expired?

I've actually tried to contact the library's author via Nuget's website, but didn't receive any response so far. Thanks for your kind help in advance!

Comment: Webgrease was abandoned 4 years ago. Even Codeplex was abandoned in that time. You'll have to upgrade to newer tooling. You can download the source while Codeplex is still available and build it with a new certificate but that's only a stopgap

Comment: At least one replacement is available by Microsoft's Mads Kristensen [BundlerMinifier](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier).

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply! I was thinking about building with a new certificate. The only question is whether it is legal to do it? (we distribute assemblies to customers' sites). As to Webgrease, it seems to be under "MS-.NET-Library License", and I am not sure who I should contact to clarify whether I can build and sign the code with my own certificate (I sent an email to webgrease@microsoft.com, but no response).